# how to deploy hyperkube image in a kubernetes pod?

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet, kubernetes-pod, hyperkube

I want to deploy hyperkube in a Kubernetes pod. 
I already have a Kubernetes cluster. I tried few docker images in the docker hub. But all pods are failing with some issues. 
I am not able to deploy hyperkube image in a Kubernetes pod.

Comment: If there are "some issues", would you like to share them with us?

Comment: we are getting ImagePullBackOff and Back-off restarting failed container errors.

Comment: Is there any error message to share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hyperkube` is the binary to run k8s components on the nodes. It is not intended to run inside the k8s cluster.

You may want to start with `busybox` image:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busybox
spec:
  containers:
  - image: busybox
    command:
      - sleep
      - "600"
    name: busybox
```

Comment: In my case, i want to run hyperkube in a pod.

Comment: Can you share more context why you want running hyperkube in the pod? It is interesting because unusual

Comment: For testing purpose, we cant use real nodes as cost is involved. So was thinking to create hollow nodes and use it in our testing. 
so for hollow node [which is a pod in cluster ], we need to deploy hyperkube in that pod.

Comment: Nikhil Kumar@ May you should read something about  `namespaces`? because run kubernetes inside kubernetes it the worst solution ever.